# Selected option in select Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select

My question is very simple, but I can't get it. I have a select to order elements in AngularJS with custom options. I just need to get one option selected when the page loads.

Here's my code:

```
<select ng-model="sortBy">
    <option value='priceOrder'>Price order</option>
    <option value='price'>Price - +</option>
    <option value='-price'>Price + -</option>
    <option value='weight'>Weight + -</option>
    <option value='-weight'>Weight - +</option>
</select>
```

The values comes from a Json in my `controller.js`, and I ask for order in:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in filteredGenere | filter:query | orderBy:sortBy" >.
   {{item.brand}} {{item.name}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the select box has one option selected when page loaded, you need to initialize `$scope.sortBy` in your controller like

```
$scope.sortBy = 'priceOrder';
```

Check this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/c8dLjJLxCsb92YBqBq2N?p=preview)

Comment: @ManelMusti Next time, do more research there are a lot of answer about your case...

Comment: @ManelMusti You can also initialize it using `ng-init="sortBy = 'priceOrder'"`